# Is it possible to replace the original RSS content?

Tags: nodes, feeds

Is it possible to replace the original RSS generated for the front page by custom content?

I know how to create custom RSS channels using views, but not how to replace the original RSS.

Answer (score 4):

When editing the Feed display of your view you have the **Feed settings** box with two settings there - Path and Attach to. If you set Path to 'rss.xml' or if you're using a view for your frontpage and you choose it in "Attach to", that should do the trick.